# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

Can someone just tell me if this is a correct way to prove it.

let $(a,b)$ be a nonempty open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Then by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $a<q<b$.

Case 1: $b-q<1$ then there is a rational $q_0$ s.t. $q<q_0<b$ but since $b-q<1$, it can not be the case that $q_0\in \mathbb{Z}$

case 2: $b-q\ge1$ then there exists rational $q_0$ s.t. $a<q<q_0<q+1\le b$. Again $q_0\notin \mathbb{Z}$  $ \ \ \ $ $_\square$

Does this work?

Comment: I'm afraid this makes no sense at all. Your aim, to exhibit $q_0 \in (a,b)$ with $q_0 \in \mathbb{Q}\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb{Z}$, is reasonable. But after that, I can't even see what you are _trying_ to do.

Comment: which part are you confused by?

Comment: nm I see the problem. its like I assumed q was an integer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb R$.
Set
$$
q=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\dfrac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n} & \text{if} & \dfrac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\not\in\mathbb Z, \\
\dfrac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}+\dfrac{1}{2n} & \text{if} & \dfrac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n} \in\mathbb Z.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $q\in\mathbb Q\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb Z$ and $\lvert x-q_n\rvert<\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Note. By $\lfloor x\rfloor$ we denote the integer part of $x$.

Comment: we have not learned of sequences, all we have is the axioms, and density of the rationals and irrationals, Archimedes principle, and a few more little things that fall out from these.

Comment: It's OK. Then replace $q_n$ above by $q$ and you have a rational close to a real.

Comment: then what is n in your function?

Comment: But I could say for interval (a,b) consider q rational in (a,b)
if q is not an integer we are done, if q is an integer we can find an n in N such that q+1/n < b and of course q+1/n is NOT an integer. Does that work?

Comment: "is not an integer for n>1 " is what I meant.

Comment: Yes, this argument looks fine.